# Ctrl+Shift+C/V does not work Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: debian, keyboard, terminal, shortcuts, hotkeys

I’ve just installed Debian 8 Jessie with Cinnamon 2.2 and launched gnome-terminal. But I can’t copy/paste text using keyboard: pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> only causes language switch. What can I do to fix that? In Ubuntu 14.04 all worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Debian 8, gnome-terminal's preferences show the expected short-cut (for me), and testing the short cut works.

However, you may have fallen into the trap laid by terminator's maintainer, who [hijacked](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/terminator/+changelog) the `x-xterminal-emulator` priority a couple of years ago.  I did not observe that in Ubuntu 14.04, but it is present in Debian 8.  If you are using "terminal", this nuisance can be worked around using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

For what it's worth, this is what I use:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
[sudo] password for tom: 
There are 20 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/xterm-dev                60        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/kterm                    21        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/lilyterm                 20        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/lxterminal               40        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper    30        manual mode
  9            /usr/bin/mlterm                   20        manual mode
  10           /usr/bin/mrxvt-full               10        manual mode
  11           /usr/bin/pterm                    20        manual mode
  12           /usr/bin/roxterm                  50        manual mode
  13           /usr/bin/stterm                   15        manual mode
  14           /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  15           /usr/bin/urxvt                    20        manual mode
  16           /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  17           /usr/bin/vala-terminal            50        manual mode
  18           /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  19           /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
  20           /usr/bin/xterm-dev                60        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Likewise, [vala-terminal](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/v/vala-terminal/unstable_changelog) does this.  Both are less functional, for instance, than gnome-terminal.